# What is the difference between $@ and $* in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

In the book "Linux Shell Scripting Cookbook"

It says `$@` expands as `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and so on and `$*` expands as `$1c$2c$3`, where `c` is the first character of `IFS`.

What's the difference between `$@` and `$*` and what `IFS` means?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

IFS is the internal field separator, it basically means what the shell recognises as what seperates words.

So to run the following command

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Would cause the shell to recognise new lines as seperators.

$ is the sign of something being assigned to a variable

However the numbers are reserved for script inputs.

So $1 would be a variable input, $2 would be a second variable input.

$@ is all of the parameters passed to the script.

So if you run the command

```
bash command.sh bork woof meow
```

This would be the value of the above listed variables

```
  $1 = bork
  $2 = woof
  $3 = meow
  $@ = bork woof meow
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to improve on the explanation given in the manuals.  For instance, `dash(1)` says:

> ### `$@`
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the expansion occurs within double-quotes, each positional parameter expands as a separate argument.  If there are no positional
>                     parameters, the expansion of `@` generates zero arguments, even when `@` is double-quoted.  What this basically means, for example, is if `$1` is “`abc`” and `$2` is “`def ghi`”, then `"$@"` expands to the
>                     two arguments:                        `"abc"` `"def ghi"`

We can demonstrate the difference between `$*` and `$@` with some examples:

```
$ set 1 "2 3"
$ printf '"%s"\n' "$@"
"1"
"2 3"
$ printf '"%s"\n' $@
"1"
"2"
"3"
$ printf '"%s"\n' "$*"
"1 2 3"
$ printf '"%s"\n' $*
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

The manual page also describes `IFS`:

> ### `IFS`
>
> Input Field Separators.  This is normally set to ⟨space⟩, ⟨tab⟩, and ⟨newline⟩.  See the *White Space Splitting* section for more details.